# How I can configure Symfony in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ubuntu-15.10, visual-studio-code

I have installed [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) on **Ubuntu 15.10** and I need this to recognize all features of Symfony Framework to develop.

I have not found a way to recognize me internal functions, services, so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Code has [basic PHP support](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/php) built in, but as of now, I don't think there is a specific Symfony Plugin that would give you the deep framework integration you'd get with the [Symfony Eclipse Plugin](http://symfony.dubture.com/) or [PHPStorm](http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/08/symfony-development-using-phpstorm/).

If someone ever creates such an extension, the [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) would probably be the right place to look for it.